# AngularJS $templateCache for directive templates via grunt plugin

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, gruntjs

`grunt-angular-templates` works well in my app for templates called with `$routeProvider`. However, I'm having some trouble getting it to work with templates defined in directives.

Some background...

Within my `index.html` file I have several custom directives for the overall site design with their own templates. I do this to keep it more modular. The overall site design has a lot of components, so I don't want the `index.html` cluttered.

Here is an example of a directive:

**navigation.js**

```
app.directive('navigation', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'src/components/navigation.html',
        controller: 'NavigationController as navCtrl'
    };
})
```

**templates.js** *(compiled via grunt-angular-templates)*

```
angular.module('app').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {

     $templateCache.put('src/components/navigation.html', '<nav>Nav here</nav>'

     // Other templates here too
);
```

The directive's `$templateCache` is being defined in the sample I gave above, but I still get additional HTTP requests for all directive-defined templates. All other templates from my routes work great.

I'd like to leverage `grunt-angular-templates` for *all* my templates; not just those called by the routes. Am I missing a step here? If this isn't possible, what other alternatives do I have to reduce the initial requests from the server?